# What are the first two moments of this stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, poisson-distribution

**The setup.** Consider a [doubly stochastic Poisson (i.e. Cox) process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox_process), which is a Poisson arrival process $X_t$ with stochastic intensity function $\lambda_t$, i.e., a Poisson process whose rate is itself a stochastic process.

I try to compute the expected value and the variance of $X_t$ for a variety of rate processes $\lambda_t$.

I already computed the distribution of $X_t$, which is given by $$ P(X_t=k)=\frac{1}{k!} E\left[ \left( \int_0^t \lambda_s ds \right)^k \exp \left( -\int_0^t \lambda_s ds \right) \right],$$ see for example [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.2884v2.pdf).

**The Problem.** I realize it is impossible to give a closed form expression for the moments of $X_t$ for arbitrary rate processes $\lambda_t$, but for some special ones it should be possible.

I already fail for the case where $\lambda_t$ is a simple Bernoulli Process, i.e., $$ \lambda_t \mbox{ i.i.d. with }, ~ P(\lambda_t=1)=\frac{1}{2}, ~ P(\lambda_t=3)=\frac{1}{2}. $$ Can anyone give me a hint on how to start? The question therefore boils down to

> How can I compute $$ E\left[ \left( \int_0^t \lambda_s ds \right)^k \exp \left( -\int_0^t \lambda_s ds \right) \right] $$ if $\lambda_t$ is the stochastic process above?

Another example that would interest me would be $$ \lambda_t \hat = \mbox{ arrival times of another Poisson process}. $$

Comment: The case when $(\lambda_t)$ is i.i.d. Bernoulli is pathological (and I fail to understand how your answer below addresses it) since, to begin with, the integrals $$\Lambda_t=\int_0^t\lambda_sds$$ do not even exist. When the process $(\Lambda_t)$ is well defined, simply use $$E(X_t)=\sum_{k\geqslant0}kP(X_t=k)=E\left(\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac1{(k-1)!} \Lambda_t^k \exp(-\Lambda_t)\right)=E(\Lambda_t).$$ Likewise, $$E(X_t(X_t-1))=E(\Lambda_t^2),$$ which yields the variance of $X_t$.

Comment: @Did so can you never compute the first integral? That would mean you can't really work with the probability distribution of a doubly stochastic poisson process

Comment: @dleal Huh? No, that means the specific case the OP suggests does not work.

Comment: @Did I am confused because the integrand is a stochastic process (not the density function). Do you have any references of how to compute these integrals? How are they called ?

Comment: @dleal Sorry but it seems you are embarking on a quite different question (and possibly, but I am not sure, completely avoiding to read what I wrote). Thus, comments on a 3 years old post are not the right place for this, simply ask another question.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out myself: For the process $\lambda_t$ given in the question, we compute \begin{align} P(X_t=k) &= \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{\omega \in \lbrace \omega_1, \omega_2 \rbrace} \left( \int_0^t \lambda_s(\omega)ds \right)^k \exp \left( - \int_0^t \lambda_s(\omega)ds \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{\omega \in \lbrace \omega_1, \omega_2 \rbrace} \frac{(2t)^k\exp(-2t)}{2} = \frac{(2t)^k\exp(-2t)}{k!}. \end{align} Therefore, we can compute the first two moments as follows \begin{align} E[X_t] &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k \frac{(2t)^k\exp(-2t)}{k!} \\ &= \exp(-2t) \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2t)^k}{(k-1)!} \\ &= 2t \exp(-2t) \exp(2t) = 2t\end{align} and \begin{align} \operatorname{var}[X_t] &= \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2 \frac{(2t)^k\exp(-2t)}{k!} \right) - (2t)^2 \\ &= ... = 4t^2+2t-4t^2 = 2t \end{align}